# Enable/Detect external monitor from XP command line

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, multiple-monitors, external-display

Is there a command line utility that can enable (and clone) an external display in Windows XP?

In Windows 7, we can do

```
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

Is there an XP equivalent to this, or some other way to do this in a scriptable manner?